# Motion detection without disk writes

Tags: raspberry-pi

I need to take video frames from pi and send them further to `zmq` socket. These should be filtered to those only where some movement takes place on the scene.

Another requrement is to completely avoid disk writes. My idea is to use [Motion](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html) and redirect all file output to `/dev/shm`. My process will read from there
and send further. `Motion` will be setup to save frames at the rate allowing to handle and remove them before memory is exhausted.

It would be great to have another solution which could give me frames one-by-one through the same process address space.

Comment: You can set a folder for using memory cache in fstab and set a maximum size to avoid consuming all memory.
tmpfs /var/log  tmpfs defaults,noatime,size=64m 0 0